# NSSet and duplicates, I need the duplicates?

Tags: cocoa, core-data

I have a core data project, with several entities which have relationships. I was using NSSet to pull the data, but discovered that NSSet removes duplicates - at least this is what is happening in my program.

I created entities and attributes in the model, then created associated NSManagedObjects so I could write custom methods. I have an `ArrayController` connected to an entity and a table connected to the `arrayController`. Column 0 displays the Order and column 1 displays the total for that Order - Order has a to-many relationship to item.

So column 2 bindings are set to the `arrayController` with modelKeyPath set to the `returnBalance` method.

I have the following method in the NSManagedObject.

```
-(NSString *)returnBalance{

 NSSet *setTotal = [self valueForKeyPath:@"item.cost"];

 NSArray *array = [setTotal allObjects];

 double ttl = 0.0;

 for (NSNumber *d in array) {

    ttl = ttl + [d doubleValue];

 }
 NSNumber *total = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:ttl];
 return [total stringValue];
}
```

Everything is working except NSSet removes duplicates. I have searched and have not found another way to pull the info from the relationship data. Any thoughts?

[EDIT]---------------

As for the Schema, I have 3 entities (Job, Order and Items). With a to-many relationship from Job -> Order -> Item. One Job has many order and each order has many Items. Items consist of a `name` and a `cost`.

I have a 2 column `NSTableView` on the window listing the Orders in column 0 and want the Total for that order in Column 1. So at a glance, I can see all the order and the total for each of them. If you click on an Order, there is a second `NSTableView` which displays all the items for that order.

Functional wise everything "works"... just using NSSet does not provide ALL the data (i.e. duplicates).

The `Order` entity has an associated NSManagedObject which is where I placed the `-(NSString *) returnBalance` method.

--[MORE]-----
I've attempted a couple more ways, and all seam to remove duplicates - what's going on?

```
 NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[self valueForKeyPath:@"item.cost"], nil];

 NSString *costString = [self valueForKeyPath:@"item.cost"];
```

Always the same, not all the data is there. However, on the window, the second `NSTableView` shows all the data - so it's there.

Comment: Yes, that's the definition of `NSSet`.  Maybe you will get better help if you explain your schema and what you are actually trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a method. The keypath for total cost of an order is `item.cost.@sum`.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I've tried that and I receive an error. `item.cost.@sum` produces a `...is not supported. key path: cost.@sum`. And using `@sum.item.cost` produces a similar error `...is not supported. Key path: cost`. I have everything bound so not sure why, that's probably a different question. I wanted to use a method so I could have more flexibility to manipulate the data if needed. Is there no way to pull **ALL** the data from an entity to an array without using a `fetchRequest`?

Comment: You can't have duplicate items, all data is in the set. Is cost a string or a number?

Comment: Cost is a Number. My current solution is using an NSFetch, but would like to see if there is a better way.